# Format numbers with css

Tags: css

Is it possible to format numbers using css ?

When I have `7000000.00`, I would like it displayed as `7 000 000.00`

I know I could write a backend (php, perl...) function or a javascript function that could return the formatted number but...

The numbers that I want to format are into a cell. I would like to have something like

`<td class="myformat">7000000.00</td>`
or
`<td><span class="myformat">7000000.00<span></td>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently CSS does not format numbers in the way you are hoping although it does [look like it's being discussed](http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting). For now you're best bet is to stick with server-side formatting. You could do it with JavaScript but that wouldn't be as reliable as server side technologies since users can turn it off.